# Ramda group then convert siblings to children

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

In ramda.js how can I group and sort a list by a field and then move all but the first item of each group into children of that item?

Eg below where I have grouped by name and sorted by date descending:

```
[{ id: 1, name: 'bob', date: '2007-03-05', count: 15},
 { id: 2, name: 'bob', date: '2007-03-04', count: 32},
 { id: 3, name: 'bob', date: '2007-03-01', count: 27},
 { id: 4, name: 'jack', date: '2007-03-04', count: 3},
 { id: 5, name: 'jack', date: '2007-02-22', count: 5}]
```

Into

```
[{ id: 1, name: 'bob', date: '2007-03-05', count: 15,
   children: [{ id: 2, name: 'bob', date: '2007-03-04', count: 32},
   { id: 3, name: 'bob', date: '2007-03-01', count: 27}]
 },
 { id: 4, name: 'jack', date: '2007-03-04', count: 3,
   children: [{ id: 5, name: 'jack', date: '2007-02-22', count: 5}]
 }
 ]
```

I know that I can grab the top item of the entire list with R.head and the rest with R.tail, and then add it as a child with R.merge, but I don't know how to grab just the top or tail of a group within a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach:

```
const fn = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('name')),
  values,
  map(lift(assoc('children'))(tail, head))
);
```

If you want to include the sort in this, you can add this after `values,`:

```
  map(sort(descend(prop('date')))),
```

If this is obscure: `map(lift(assoc('children'))(tail, head))` you could replace it with the equivalent:

```
  map((group) => assoc('children', tail(group), head(group)))
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20people%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20id%3A%201%2C%20name%3A%20%27bob%27%2C%20date%3A%20%272007-03-05%27%2C%20count%3A%2015%7D%2C%0A%20%7B%20id%3A%202%2C%20name%3A%20%27bob%27%2C%20date%3A%20%272007-03-04%27%2C%20count%3A%2032%7D%2C%0A%20%7B%20id%3A%203%2C%20name%3A%20%27bob%27%2C%20date%3A%20%272007-03-01%27%2C%20count%3A%2027%7D%2C%0A%20%7B%20id%3A%204%2C%20name%3A%20%27jack%27%2C%20date%3A%20%272007-03-04%27%2C%20count%3A%203%7D%2C%0A%20%7B%20id%3A%205%2C%20name%3A%20%27jack%27%2C%20date%3A%20%272007-02-22%27%2C%20count%3A%205%7D%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20fn%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20groupBy%28prop%28%27name%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20values%2C%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20map%28sort%28descend%28prop%28%27date%27%29%29%29%29%0A%20%20map%28lift%28assoc%28%27children%27%29%29%28tail%2C%20head%29%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Afn%28people%29%3B)**.

Comment: this is amazing

Answer (score 3):

You haven't yet grouped them, just ordered them by the name. To group them into an array of arrays, use [`R.groupWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupWith):

```
R.groupWith(R.eqProps("name"))
```

After applying that to your data, use a `map` to create an object from each group.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you could get desired result

```
const groupByName = groupBy(obj => obj.name);
const sortByDate = sortBy(obj => obj.date);
const grouped = pipe(groupByName, map(sortByDate), values);

reduce( (acc, val) => {
 acc.push(merge(head(val), {children: tail(val)}));
 return acc;
}, [], grouped(data));
```

[Ramda snippet](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27bob%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20%272007-03-05%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%2015%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27bob%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20%272007-03-04%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%2032%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27bob%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20%272007-03-01%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%2027%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%204%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27jack%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20%272007-03-04%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%203%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%205%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27jack%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20%272007-02-22%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%205%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20groupByName%20%3D%20groupBy%28obj%20%3D%3E%20obj.name%29%3B%0Aconst%20sortByDate%20%3D%20sortBy%28obj%20%3D%3E%20obj.date%29%3B%0Aconst%20grouped%20%3D%20pipe%28groupByName%2C%20map%28sortByDate%29%2C%20values%29%3B%0A%0Areduce%28%20%28acc%2C%20val%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20acc.push%28merge%28head%28val%29%2C%20%7Bchildren%3A%20tail%28val%29%7D%29%29%3B%0A%20return%20acc%3B%0A%7D%2C%20%5B%5D%2C%20grouped%28data%29%29%3B%0A%0A%0A)

Answer (score 2):

There are probably better ways to do it, but I think that's a start:

```
function yourAnswer (data) {
  const groupByName = groupBy((person) => person.name)
  return (
    Object.values(groupByName(data))
    .map((g) => g.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)) // sort by ascending id
    .map(function(g) { // for each group, sorted by id
      const o = Object.assign(g[0]) // create an object from the minimal id
      o['children'] = g.slice(1) // assign 'children' to be equal the other objects in the group
      return o
  })
)}

let data = [{ id: 1, name: 'bob', date: '2007-03-05', count: 15},
            { id: 2, name: 'bob', date: '2007-03-04', count: 32},
            { id: 3, name: 'bob', date: '2007-03-01', count: 27},
            { id: 4, name: 'jack', date: '2007-03-04', count: 3},
            { id: 5, name: 'jack', date: '2007-02-22', count: 5}]

console.log(yourAnswer(data))
```

Try it at the [ramda repl](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?function%20yourAnswer%20%28data%29%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20groupByName%20%3D%20groupBy%28%28person%29%20%3D%3E%20person.name%29%0A%20%20return%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20Object.values%28groupByName%28data%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20.map%28%28g%29%20%3D%3E%20g.sort%28%28a%2C%20b%29%20%3D%3E%20a.id%20-%20b.id%29%29%20%2F%2F%20sort%20by%20ascending%20id%0A%20%20%20%20.map%28function%28g%29%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20for%20each%20group%2C%20sorted%20by%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20o%20%3D%20Object.assign%28g%5B0%5D%29%20%2F%2F%20create%20an%20object%20from%20the%20minimal%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20o%5B%27children%27%5D%20%3D%20g.slice%281%29%20%2F%2F%20assign%20%27children%27%20to%20be%20equal%20the%20other%20objects%20in%20the%20group%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20o%0A%20%20%7D%29%0A%29%7D%0A%0Alet%20data%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20id%3A%201%2C%20name%3A%20%27bob%27%2C%20date%3A%20%272007-03-05%27%2C%20count%3A%2015%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%202%2C%20name%3A%20%27bob%27%2C%20date%3A%20%272007-03-04%27%2C%20count%3A%2032%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%203%2C%20name%3A%20%27bob%27%2C%20date%3A%20%272007-03-01%27%2C%20count%3A%2027%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%204%2C%20name%3A%20%27jack%27%2C%20date%3A%20%272007-03-04%27%2C%20count%3A%203%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%205%2C%20name%3A%20%27jack%27%2C%20date%3A%20%272007-02-22%27%2C%20count%3A%205%7D%5D%0A%0Aconsole.log%28yourAnswer%28data%29%29%0A%0A).